# copy first three letters of some textbox and paste to another textbox

Tags: vb5

I know its a silly question but I still want to know it. I have two textboxes, textbox1 and textbox2. I entered some text in textbox1. Now I want that the first 3 characters of textbox1 first to be displayed in textbox2 when I move from textbox1 to textbox2 using tab index or by clicking my mouse on textbox2. I know I can make us of the mouse over event, but it will be great if I get some good opinions from you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
Private Sub textbox2_GotFocus()
 Dim length As Integer
 length = Len(textbox1.Text)
 If length > 3 Then length = 3
 textbox2.Text = Left$(textbox1.Text, length)
End Sub
```

The GotFocus event will trigger if you click on the textbox or if you use tab key.